# Entity Framework Core 3.0 - scaffold with design time services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 3.0 in my app, and since I want to use singularization/pluralization I have added a Design Time Services class:

```
 public class MyDesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
    {
        public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IPluralizer, MyPluralizer>();
        }
    }

    public class MyPluralizer : IPluralizer
    {
        public string Pluralize(string name)
        {
            return Inflector.Pluralize(name) ?? name;
        }

        public string Singularize(string name)
        {
            return Inflector.Singularize(name) ?? name;
        }
    }
```

but when I use Scaffold-DbContext from the Package Manager console as before:

> Scaffold-DbContext
>   "Server=localhost;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force

the design time services are not invoked.

How do I scaffold / generate my code and also invoke this?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to run the command at the root of your project:

> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=localhost;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -f

Comment: Where, in the Package Manager console?

Comment: When I run it in the cmd, I get: unrecognized option '-OutputDir'.